# How to configure Symfony with AWS DocDb?

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, symfony, aws-documentdb

I am trying to configure Symfony to connect to AWS DocDb using SSL and a pem file. What options should we set in the config.yml file and where should the pem file be?

I'm relatively new to AWS and I stumbled upon the following situation:
One Amazon Linux EC2 instance, Apache 2.4 installed (httpd).
Attached to it, one cluster with two DocDb Instances (Engine version docdb 3.6.0).

Our app using Symfony has to connect to the DB, up until now we didn't use SSL and the conf file looked like this:

```
app/config/config.yml
doctrine_mongodb:
    connections:
        default:
            server: mongodb://localhost:27017
            options: {}
    default_database: 
    document_managers:
```

AWS provides rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem to connect with SSL and it's perfectly working with SSH.

But when trying :

```
server: mongodb://localhost:27017/?ssl=true&ssl_ca_certs=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem
```

in the config.yml file

We are just getting in the symfony logs:

```
Uncaught PHP Exception MongoConnectionException [...] TLS handshake failed.
```

Can we configure symfony to work with pem files? Thanks!

Comment: Although we recommend TLS, and it is the default, you can optionally turn off TLS if you desire: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/documentdb/latest/developerguide/security.encryption.ssl.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, we are under HIPAA regulation (handling sensitive data) hence we are not allowed to reduce the security of the architecture ...